# Testing subscription in Android: item not found

Tags: android, testing, in-app-billing, subscription, google-play

I am trying to test the new subscriptions in Google Play but the service returns "Item not found".

I've used the identifier "android.test.purchased" to test. 
With this identifier I can test perfectly the *normal* in-app product, but whith subscription it doesn't work.

In the Google Play Console I added a subscription, and it is published.

Do I have to use the real subscription identifier and pay for testing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I have been looking for this , and am guessing that you may have already solved your problem.But this might help others
 Even I have been unable to find any documentation about test product-ids for subscription however [Testing In-App billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)  suggests only use of 4 reserved static product ids. This makes me infer that there is no test-id for subscription.

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation fails to mention this fact. Anyway, to reiterate, the _reserved product IDs can only be used for in-app products_.

Answer (score 2):

yes,you will have to use real subscription and pay (you can cancel later).
there's no test for subscription.
notice that you will have to send in your request 
api version=2 and product type should be "subs".

Comment: Any official info from Google?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play has already implemented a sandbox to test subscriptions and issue purchases. You need to publish your app in beta and after a few hours of doing that the test users(added in Google Play dev console) can make test purchases(these are not charged) in your app. They can even make subscription test purchases. A test subscription automatically renews every day(until canceled from Google Play) irrespective of the subscription duration.
Although, please note that the test user(Google account) must have a valid credit card added to the Google Wallet account in order to make test purchases(which are not charged). While making the purchase, the purchase confirmation dialog clearly mentions that this is a test purchase and you will not be charged.